# How can I replace numbers in a data grid view with images?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I receive a table from a database that I assign to my data grid, but I want to replace the numbers in the "tag" column with images but I have problems doing so. At the moment I have tried with a single number without success. The type of the column is textbox, but changing it to an image does not work for me either.

I have tried to use CellFormating and I can find the field that interests me but I do not know how to replace the number with an image.

```cs
private void DgvCriticasUser_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dgvCriticasUser.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "tag")
    {
        if (e.Value.ToString() == "1")
        {
            Bitmap tag1 = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(@"C:\Users\guill\Desktop\ProyectoIntegradoVerde-master\ProyectoEquipoVerde\ProyectoEquipoVerde\imagenes\grupo_w.png");

            DataGridViewImageCell iCell = new DataGridViewImageCell();
            iCell.Value = tag1;

            e.Value = iCell;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another route you can take is to [hide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-hide-columns-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control) the "tag" column:

```
this.dataGridView1.Columns["YourColumnName"].Visible = false;
```

Create and [Insert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumncollection.insert?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewColumnCollection_Insert_System_Int32_System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewColumn_) a `DataGridViewImageColumn` at the desired `index` (for example 0):

```
DataGridViewImageColumn imageCol = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
this.dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, buttonColumn);
```

Then set the value of the image column in the `CellFormatting` event handler similar to the way you are attempting now.